# Error in pandas "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'round'"

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am building a machine learning model, after normalization, I am trying to round up values but pandas DataFrame throwing an error

```
 "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'round'"
```

Example Code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("Des_Cor_remove.csv")
>>> df.round(2)
```

And I'm not able to figure out the exact problem as earlier I have used this method to round up the data frames, Please help.

Comment: what is your pandas version?

Comment: @seralouk     Pandas version=_'0.13.1'

Comment: this is the problem update to latest pandas. use: `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Answer (score 1):

`Update` your `pandas` module to the latest version.

---

*Use*:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Next, you can use this function.

---

**Example**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([3, 3]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['first', 'second', 'third'])
df.round()

          A    B    C
first   1.0  0.0  0.0
second  1.0  1.0  1.0
third   0.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Does not help. Still the same error.